# How to make a child div same height as parent and make its width equal its height?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I want to place a div inside another div, but the child div must have the same height as the parent div and its width must equal its height. However, I can't use absolute values for the height/width because the container's (parent's) dimensions aren't absolute values.

Essentially something that looks sort of like this:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------|
|           |                                              |
|    child  |                                              |
|     div   |                    parent div                |
|           |                                              |
|----------------------------------------------------------|
```

I don't know how to make the child's width equal its height. It's simple to set `height: 100%` on the child, but I've got no clue as to how I can set its width relatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use modern CSS, you can use

```css
height: 100%;
aspect-ratio: 1;
```

on your child to force it into being a square.

(`aspect-ratio` is supported by [80% of users and all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio))